# Chrome Extension API v17: webRequest onErrorOccurred.addListener

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am attempting to set up a chrome extension similar to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/samples.html#webrequest except that it would us the onErrorOccurred listener instead to redirect to a specific known page when the get request fails for any reason.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Custom Error",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Redirect all navigation errors to specified location/file.",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": ["error_listener.html"]
  }
}
```

error_listener.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
  chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
      function onErrorOccurred(details) {
        console.log('onBeforeRequest ', details.url);
        return { redirectUrl: 'http://www.google.com' }
      }, 
      {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
      //{urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]}
  );
        //chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "http://www.google.com", ['blocking']});
        //alert("what?");
</script>
```

The extension loads without any errors indicated yet the browser tab is not redirected. I have tried this using both Chrome 16 and Chrome 17; when using Chrome 16, I did change "chrome.webRequest" to "chrome.experimental.webRequest" and added "experimental" to the permissions list.

So far it seems like the problem is that while the extension appears to be loaded when looking at chrome://extensions, the files are not actually loaded--when using Developer Tools, I don't see any reference to error_listener.html.

I have also tried running Chrome 17 with the following flags:

```
8611  25/01/12-11:22:05> google-chrome --restore-last-session 
--debug-on-start --log-level=0 --enable-logging 
--enable-extension-activity-logging --enable-extension-alerts 
--debug-plugin-loading --debug-print | tee > log1.txt
```

Obviously, I am just kind of poking around in the dark with that command line. Anyone have any clue as to how to get this working? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome 16, you should be using:

```
"background_page": "background.html"
```

rather than

```
"background": {
    "page": ["error_listener.html"]
}
```

This fixes the problem with the background page not loading. It looks like this may have changed in the [trunk docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/background_pages.html) compared to the [current docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), and I'm not sure which version of Chrome starts implementing the new manifest.json format.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem of getting the page to load (there is now the option to "Inspect active views" for that extension in chrome://extensions) , now I just need to debug the javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no webRequest.onErrorOccurred event. You may use webNavigation.onErrorOccurred. If you want to catch DNS errors and redirect to another url you may use the code:

```
<script>
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function(details) 
{
    if (details.frameId != 0) //ignore subframes. 0 is main frame
    { return; }

    chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + details.url});
});
</script>
```